# How do i get refs value from dynamically generated array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got my data from firebase, looped through it and displayed it on the frontend. Now I am trying to get the refs value of the already displayed value when I click on it. For example, when I click on Dino, i should be able to see the value 'Dino' on my console tab of Chrome browser.

[Here is a link to the picture of the array list displayed on react frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2527o.png)

```
<ul>
    <li onClick={this.handleSubmit}>        
        {               
            Object.keys(this.props.group).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
                return(
                    <div key={keyIndex}>{keyName}</div>
                )
            })
        }
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Some code that reproduces the problem would be more useful than a picture here. Could you try setting up a demo in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that those "dino, magic & muu" are the keys in `this.props.group` you need to add an `onClick` handler to that `div`, so:

```
<div key={keyIndex} onClick={() => console.log(keyName)}>{keyName}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to bind a click event to each `div` within the `li`. I would actually rewrite it like so:

```
 <ul>    
    {               
        Object.keys(this.props.group).map( (keyName, keyIndex) => {
            return(
                <li key={keyIndex} onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this, keyName}>  
                    {keyName}
                </li>
            )
        })
    }
</ul>
```

Then your `handleSubmit` function will get the `keyName` as a param:

```
handleSubmit(keyName){
    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the this keyword was nightmare for me. Now i have seen my mistake